# code-server cannot find nodejs

Tags: server, raspberrypi, nodejs, visual-studio-code

I had a problem while trying to run code-server (visual studio code on browser), I installed it correctly via the manual process, but every time I try to run it I get this error:

`/usr/bin/code-server: 36: exec: /usr/lib/node: not found`

I immediately thought that the problem was in the installation path of nodejs, so I ran

`where nodejs`

And I got back

`/usr/bin/nodejs`

`/bin/nodejs`

I am running Raspberry Pi OS, and I reinstalled node multiple times, what should I do?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question searching the same.

I fixed it copying my node installation in the path that code-server search node.

I have code-server in `/usr/lib/code-server/bin/code-server` (because I used the installation script), if I search my node installation with `whereis node`, reports `node: /usr/bin/node`.

Such my error was `/usr/lib/code-server/bin/code-server: 36: exec: /usr/lib/code-server/lib/node: not found`, I copied `/usr/bin/node` in `/usr/lib/code-server/lib/node` and it works now.

Maybe for you works `sudo cp /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/node`